# Integer values considered by VB.Net datatable as decimals after MySQL query

Tags: mysql, vb.net, winforms, charts, datatable

In VB (Winforms) I am extracting statistics from MySQL database and the resulting datatable is used to build different charts. What made me impression is that depending on MySQL query in some cases pure integer values are considered as decimals in datatable and thus my charts look strange with their grid lines depicted with fractions of 1. Examples are below.

When I use in my query grouing the result is not what I expect. Query looks like following:

```
select Cell,Time,
sum(counter12) as counter
from h_cell
where cell='ABC' and time>='2018-05-26' and time<='2018-06-01'
group by Cell,Time
```

In this case the datatype of datatable's column 'counter' is 'System.Decimal'. I need to stress that the value is always integer. Also I cannot avoid grouing in my query. The problem is that my chart looks not right with grid lines showing values less than one.

[image]

When I design my query without grouping then datatype of the column in datatable is 'System.Int32' and then chart looks as it should.

```
select Cell,Time,
(counter12) as counter
from h_cell
where cell='ABC' and time>='2018-05-26' and time<='2018-06-01'
```

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this inconsistency?

Comment: Of what data type is the column `counter12` in the MySQL database? A possible solutions is to [CAST/CONVERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html) the column in question to Int32.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the table structure in MySQL and refer to this page for the equivalent to see why you might be getting a Decimal type: [Visual Basic / MySQL Datatypes](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/visual-basic-datatypes.html)

Something else you might try (as someone else suggested) is to cast to the data type you are expecting. The only difference is that I would not cast your column, but the result of your sum as follows:

```
select Cell,Time,
Cast(sum(counter12) As SIGNED) as counter
from h_cell
where cell='ABC' and time>='2018-05-26' and time<='2018-06-01'
group by Cell,Time
```